# Level of vaccination for safe, large, international event

Tags: covid-19, epidemiology

I've read as much as I've been able about COVID-19 all these months, but nothing comes to mind that talks about what an appropriate level of vaccination would be among international guests to a large event to make it a safe event.

Specifically, I'm thinking of a 50-100 person event next year (2021) that is planned to take place in Latin America, where early access to vaccines might be an issue. Ideally, I'd like to provide eventual guidance (as vaccine research and availability evolves, of course) about what a wise course of action will be.

**I'm curious about the risks for unvaccinated (and vaccinated?) guests if the minority (~25%), half, and the majority (~75%) of guests are already vaccinated.**

I understand that this might also depend on the efficacy of the specific vaccine. I assumed, too, that vaccinated people won't be at risk anymore, but recent reading leads me to believe that they'll be less likely to contract COVID-19, but that they won't 100% be immune to it.

**How will the interaction of vaccinated vs non-vaccinated people work in this kind of scenario?**

**Note:** I'm not expecting opinion-based answers, but rather thoughtful, fact-based deeper analyses of the range of possibilities a scenario like this will entail. As time moves on, the answers can and should become more precise, of course. I'm also not expecting a single right answer (degrees of possible scenarios given percentage variables would be better) or one right away (it absolutely is too soon to actually know). Many of the most popular articles associated with COVID-19 activity risk assessment right now have to work with uncertainties and levels of plausibility, and I expect answers to do so as well. Most of all, I want to make sure this question is out there and explored at all, since it hasn't been covered much.

Comment: Hard to say without a working vaccine and results thereof in circulation.